# Dialogflow agent.add not working properly

Tags: javascript, api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

```
function readfromdb(agent) {
  //agent.add("Hi");
  var booksinlibrary = [];
  var books = admin.database().ref('data/books');
  return books.on("value",function(data){
    var _data = data.val();
    for (var key in _data){
      console.log("key is",key);
      var book = _data[key];
      console.log("book is",book);
      var name = book.name;
      var author = book.author;
      var res = `name is ${name} and author is ${author}`;
      booksinlibrary.push(res);
    } 
    console.log(booksinlibrary[0]);
    agent.add(`Books available are ${booksinlibrary[0]}`);
  }); 
}
```

The information is not getting displayed on the assistant simulator and showing a not available status.I am able to log the data but not able to be displayed. while commenting out the 2nd line agent.add("Hi"), it is getting displayed on the simulator as "Hi".

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is that `readfromdb()` must return a Promise, since it is doing an asynchronous operation, and the library expects a Promise to be returned so it knows to wait for the asynchronous operation (your database call) to be completed before it sends back any values.

Since you are using the callback form of `on()`, the return value is the callback function. So you're returning a function, rather than a Promise.

Instead, you should be using the [Promise form of `once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) which returns a Promise, so you'll do your work in a `then()` block, which also gets returned. Your code might look something like this:

```
function readfromdb(agent) {
  //agent.add("Hi");
  var booksinlibrary = [];
  var books = admin.database().ref('data/books');
  return books.once("value").then( data => {
    var _data = data.val();
    for (var key in _data){
      console.log("key is",key);
      var book = _data[key];
      console.log("book is",book);
      var name = book.name;
      var author = book.author;
      var res = `name is ${name} and author is ${author}`;
      booksinlibrary.push(res);
    } 
    console.log(booksinlibrary[0]);
    agent.add(`Books available are ${booksinlibrary[0]}`);
  }); 
}
```

It is also important to use `once()` since `on()` sets up a callback every time the value changes, which you don't need (and which won't typically work as part of a Dialogflow webhook). You just want to query the value so you can return it.

Comment: Great! If an answer helps, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.